# Filtrar Datos en DataGridView ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

quisiera que me ayudaran en como filtrar los datos que me entrega en un datagrid con datos que me entrega esta tabla, mi idea es hacerla como una especie de Excel cuando uno quiere filtrar datos, de momento tengo este estoy usando textbox y al momento de realizar una consulta no me deja realizarla dandome errores que no existen datos o simplemente no realiza ninguna accion en la ventana

[image: imagen del proyecto en desarrollo]

y este es el codigo que estoy utilizando

```
namespace CRUD_RRHH_BUSQUEDA.Listado_Busqueda
{
    public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=***************;Integrated Security=True");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM DATOS_PERSONALES", cn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            this.DatosPersona.DataSource = dt;
            DatosPersona.DataBind();
        }
        void consulta_RUN()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM DATOS_PERSONALES WHERE RUN like '" + TextBoxRUN.Text + "%'", cn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            this.DatosPersona.DataSource = dt;
            DatosPersona.DataBind();

        
        }
        protected void ButtonBusqueda_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            consulta_RUN();
            consulta_AP();
            
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que ya tienes la búsqueda por el dato "RUN". solamente debes agregar el resto de columnas y usar los signos % en el comando [Like](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo:

```
--CREANDO VARIABLE TIPO TABLA
DECLARE @DATOS_PERSONALES AS TABLE 
(id int identity(1,1), RUN VARCHAR(100), ApellidoPaterno VARCHAR(100),
 ApellidoMaterno VARCHAR(100))

--AGREGANDO UN REGISTRO
INSERT INTO @DATOS_PERSONALES
VALUES ('RUN1','GONZALEZ', 'CASTILLO')

--CONSULTANDO LOS DATOS
SELECT * FROM @DATOS_PERSONALES
WHERE RUN like '%RUN1%' OR ApellidoPaterno
like '%GONZALEZ%' OR ApellidoMaterno like '%ROS%'
```

El Resultado sería el siguiente:

```
RUN         ApellidoPaterno       ApellidoMaterno
----------------------------------------------------
RUN1          GONZALEZ            CASTILLO
```